# Binding an Observable Collection of Objects to a RadTreeListView

Tags: c#, xaml, telerik, observablecollection, radtreeview

as the Title states I just want to bind my ObservableCollection. I followed some only examples and looked at the telerik Website but seemingly Iam doing something wrong. Below is my DataContext as well as the Xaml code reduced to the necessary stuff. I you need more Ino iam happy to provide it.
All o the Dog attributes have getter (and setter) and are o the datatypes Ushort, int and String.

While executing I get this Error note:

System.Windows.Data Error: 40 : BindingExpression path error: 'bsdHeader' property not found on 'object' ''MainViewModel' (HashCode=19289328)'. BindingExpression:Path=dogs; DataItem='MainViewModel' (HashCode=19289328); target element is 'RadPaneGroup' (Name=''); target property is 'ItemsSource' (type 'IEnumerable')

EDIT: this Error disappeared after i added a get/set to the Observable collection dogs and moved the "new ObservableCollection" part into the Method.

```
public ObservableCollection<Dog> dogs = new ObservableCollection<Dog>();

  public void CreateList()
    {




        foreach(Dog dog in ListofDogs)
        {
            dogs.Add(dog);
        }

    }
```

.

```
<telerik:RadPaneGroup Grid.Row="3"  ItemsSource="{Binding Dog, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">


    <telerik:RadPane Header="dogs" PaneHeaderVisibility="Hidden">
        <telerik:RadTreeListView>
            <telerik:RadTreeListView.ChildTableDefinitions>
                <telerik:TreeListViewTableDefinition ItemsSource="{Binding color}" />
                <telerik:TreeListViewTableDefinition ItemsSource="{Binding amountOfLegs}" />
                <telerik:TreeListViewTableDefinition ItemsSource="{Binding breed}" />
            </telerik:RadTreeListView.ChildTableDefinitions>
        </telerik:RadTreeListView>
    </telerik:RadPane>
</telerik:RadPaneGroup>
```

working xaml:

```
    <telerik:RadPaneGroup>
        <telerik:RadPane Header="Dogs" PaneHeaderVisibility="Hidden">
            <telerik:RadGridView x:Name="rgv_dogs" 
                                    ItemsSource="{Binding dogs, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"  ShowGroupPanel="False" >
                <telerik:RadGridView.Columns >
                    <telerik:GridViewDataColumn DataMemberBinding="{Binding color}"/>
                    <telerik:GridViewDataColumn DataMemberBinding="{Binding amountOfLEgs}"/>
                    <telerik:GridViewDataColumn DataMemberBinding="{Binding breed}"/>
                </telerik:RadGridView.Columns>
            </telerik:RadGridView>
        </telerik:RadPane>
   </telerik:RadPaneGroup>
```

Okay, anticlimactic solution: My Visual Studio had an hickup? a collegue said maybe some update issue. After a reboot the code works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know nothing of Telerik UI, but I think you can try some options:

1. ItemSource of `telerik:RadPaneGroup` is `Dog` in your code. It looks like `Dog` is type name, not the property name of `ObservableCollection<Dog>`.
2. Is `ObservableCollection<Dog> Dogs` was declared in method? As far as I know, Property for ItemSource Binding of XAML Collections should be public Property of DataContext, except the case of binding happened in code behind.

I hope this can works with you too.

Edit: I was going to write 'can you change `public ObservableCollection<Dog> dogs = new ObservableCollection<Dog>();` to `public ObservableCollection<Dog> dogs{get;set;} = null;`?'. Because without getter and setter `dogs` is not considered as property. But it seems you already corrected that part.

Then If your telerik item still shows nothing, I recommend you to change CreateList back to declare it's own `ObservableCollection<Dog> _dogs`. But with the additional line like `dogs = _dogs` at the end, to force fire INotifyPropertyChanged of `dogs`. If this does not works too, You can see 'live visual tree' tool of Visual Studio and click the object to see it's ItemSource property. Maybe binding was happened well, but only not showing them visually.

Comment: Hi thanks or the help, I changed a few things according to your comment but unfortunatly still nothing is shown. Telerik should be the same as the regular wpf/xaml in all important points (regarding this issue). as ar as i see it it just brings more possibilities for stylation and stuff. :)

Comment: I additionally did indeed screw up the telerik elements, i correct that and added it to the post. Now at least the columns are displayed. Going to try your new inputs in a moment thx :)

Comment: Ater the changes I get BsdReader.ViewModels.MainViewModel.dogs.**get** hat null zurückgegeben.

I also added the dogs = _dogs version, without the null stuff at top but since it didnt work either (no error though) I build it back.

Comment: Your comments fixed my issue, thx. seemingly just my visual studio that didnt got that memo immidiatly....